# Xamarin Android Questions and Issues when working with WebServices (SOAP .NET 2.0)

Tags: c#, android, web-services, soap, xamarin

I've been working with Xamarin and Webservices (Stated as .NET 2.0 Webservice in Xamarin) in the past few weeks. And I've runned into a few problems that I couldn't figure a workaround yet.

1st) How do I set a timeout for the webservice? The Timeout property is ignored regardless of its value. I believe the default being used is something around 30 seconds. But I'd like 5 seconds~~.

2nd) When the WebService call any method async, using the Begin. Is there anyway to check whether the async method was completed correctly or was timed out? The only way I got to "check" is by perfoming a try/catch in the End method. If it was fired because of a timeout, it will raise an exception. But I wonder if there is some property or method somewhere that would tell me if the webservice call did timeout or was processed correctly. The webservice method being used here is "IsAlive".

```
WebService.MainService.BeginIsAlive ((ar) => 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        bool result = WebService.MainService.EndIsAlive (ar); //If timedout will raise an exception. 
        RunOnUiThread (() => 
        { 
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Running as expected...", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        });

        StartActivity (typeof(OtherScreen));
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
            //Probably timeout.
    }
}, null);
```

3rd) Is there a way to Cancel a webservice async operation? Such as "CancelIsAlive". The only method I found was Webservice.Abort. But I do not believe it is a best practice and since it is not specific, it may screw everything up.

Thanks in advance, Luís Henrique.

Comment: As my experience, Xamarin does have a lot of troubles binding to WebServices. The best chance to have everything working is using wsdl.exe tool from .net framework to generate a .cs class proxy and use it in your program. I am using it like that and timeouts work flawlesly.

Comment: I've noticed that! I'll consider generating a class proxy later on, but still if the timeout is reached how do you check the in the async method? Do you need to perform a try/catch in order to know if it reached the timeout limit or was executed normally?

Comment: To be honest, I never use the asynchronous methods because they gave me a lot of troubles, I'm creating an answer showing what I usually do

Answer (score 1):

That's what usually I do for calling WebServices and having control on them (assume your ws function needs an string and returns an string):

```
    public static void CallSomeFunction(string SomeParameter, Action<string> Ok, Action Error, Activity Context)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((object e) => {


            var proxy = new YourProxyClass();
            proxy.Timeout = 10000;

            try{

                var res = proxy.YourFunction(SomeParameter);
                Context.RunOnUiThread(() => Ok(res));

            }
            catch(Exception Ex){

                if(Error != null)
                    Context.RunOnUiThread(Error);

            }


        });
    }
```

This is how I do asynchronous tasks, use the ThreadPool to make synchronous calls, and pass some Actions to execute if all is ok or wrong. Also I'm passing a Context so my Ok and Error actions be executed in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm not marking as an answer because I hope someone will still answer my 3 original questions, but in the meantime while no one does so, I believe your code will help me a lot, thanks!