# Passing an Id from Android app to WCF Service App

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I am trying to get a listview selected item to work. I am trying to see if I can pass the selected value to a wcf and query the database from a selected county to a town. I am just wondering how I can do this?

Here is my onitem click event that I am building at the minute:

```
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  var selectedValue = parent.GetItemAtPosition(position);
  var Intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SelectLocationActivity));
  // selectedValue should already be a string but...
  Intent.PutExtra("Name", selectedValue.ToString());
  StartActivity(Intent);
}
```

I am just wondering how I can implement the calling of the wcf service app and post the selected value to it. I am using Xamarin by the way

Comment: are you per a chance using Xamarin?

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I didn't mention that at first, question updated @Gusman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set up your webservice, then just add a Service Reference in your project and all the exposed functions of your ws will be available through the proxy class which will be created when you added the reference.

Comment: Okay, so do you just add the calling of the wcf, BasicHttpBinding, etc,  into the onitemclick?

Comment: I usually set up a class named Communications which encapsulates al the calls to the service, deals with exceptions, etc, but that's my preference, you can do it as you like.

Comment: okay, so will it have this class have to be called after "var selectedValue = parent.GetItemAtPosition(position);". Sorry if I am asking all these probably simple/stupid questions. I am only new to xamarin.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but as a recomendation, add the service reference and play a bit with it, will let you a more clear view.

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks Gusman. Only thing is, how do you build the listview? Would it go in the "SelectedLocationActivity" or in the one where I am now? Sorry, hopefully this will be the last question I'll ask.

Comment: Er... don't you have a listview in your Layout file?

Comment: Also, take a look at this answer, may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294083/xamarin-android-questions-and-issues-when-working-with-webservices-soap-net-2

Comment: yup I do, I am just wondering how can I pass the information into the listview. Ok thanks

Comment: You need an Adapter, if you have just an string array you can use the built-in ArrayAdapter: `yourListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arrayOfStrings);`

Comment: onItemClick will fire when you click an item in your list, if your list does not have any items it will not fire...